# Is there a way to prevent users creating new opportunities if the last created opportunity is less than 7 days old on an account

Tags: validation-rule

Hi Iam just wondering if there is a way to prevent users creating new opportunities if the last created opportunity is less than 7 days old on an account.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity: why do you want to have this constraint?

Answer (score 6):

Create Roll-Up Summary on Account with summary type *MAX*, choose Field to Aggregate *Opportunity: Created Date*.
Create validation on Opportunity like

```
today() - Datevalue(Account.lastOppCreatedDate) < 7
```